# Loop Listview ,update database

Tags: c#, sql, listview, sql-update

My ListView is filled by a DataTable. When I check more than 1 line it doesn't update. It updates only the first line checked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (listView1.Items[i].Checked)
    {
         DataRow dr = ds.Tables["EXP"].Rows[i];

         Itemchek = dr["NUM_FAC"].ToString();

         dr["MODE_PAIE"] = "cheque";

         modeP = dr["MODE_PAIE"].ToString();
         mantantR = dr["MNT_REG"].ToString();

         try
         {
             objConn.Open();
             updateCmd.CommandText = "update EXPORT set MODE_PAI=@modeP ,MNT_REG=@mantantR where           NUM_FAC=@Itemchek";
             updateCmd.Connection = objConn;
             updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@modeP", modeP);
             updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@mantantR", mantantR);
             updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Itemchek", Itemchek);
             da.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;
             da.Update(ds, "EXP");
             objConn.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception x)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's happening because you're reusing your `SqlCommand` instance.

Modify your code to create a new one, only when you need it, and dispose it when you're finished.

```
try
{
    objConn.Open();

    using (var updateCmd = new SqlCommand(objConn))
    {
        updateCmd.CommandText =
            "update EXPORT set MODE_PAI=@modeP ,MNT_REG=@mantantR where NUM_FAC=@Itemchek";
        updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@modeP", modeP);
        updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@mantantR", mantantR);
        updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Itemchek", Itemchek);
        da.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;
        da.Update(ds, "EXP");
    }
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
}
finally
{
    objConn.Close();
}
```

You should also create a new `SqlConnection` as you need it, and dispose it. But if you're going to reuse it, then at least place the call to `Close()` in the `finally` block so that it closes your connection even if an exception is thrown.